# Why does the "sections" property in Python wikipedia package return an empty list?

Tags: python, wikipedia

I can get content of a Wikipedia section if I ask for a specific section, for example:

```
import wikipedia
print(wikipedia.WikipediaPage('Sleep Well Beast').section("Promotion"))
```

but when I try to get all the sections, I get an empty list, why?

```
print(wikipedia.WikipediaPage('Sleep Well Beast').sections)
```

According to documentation, this should give a list of sections:

https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#api

Comment: Looks like this is an old issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34869597/1761793

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `wikipedia_sections` libary using

```
pip install wikipedia_sections
```